# Showing the terms in a partial sum?

Tags: summation, algebraic-manipulation

I am trying to get

```
   s[n_]:=Sum[1/2^k,{k,1,n}]
```

to show me the actual terms involved in the $n$th partial sum and not just the sum itself. I've tried `Expand`, `Apart`, etc. to no avail. Ideas?

Edit based on early comments: Is it necessary to use `Table` to accomplish this rather than some algebraic command applied to `s[n]` or some option of `Sum`?

Comment: `s[n_] := Row[Riffle[Table[1/2^k, {k, 1, n}], "+"]]` then?

Comment: Or `s[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[1/2^# &, n, 1, Defer[Plus[##]] &]` allowing you to copy/paste the result and evaluate it.

Comment: @J.M. I am sure you are aware of the shortcut `Row[Table[1/2^k, {k, 1, n}], "+"]` to your code.

Comment: @Sasha, not until you brought it up, actually; thanks!

Comment: @J.M. `Row[list,s] inserts s as a separator between successive elements.` Damn! there is too much functionality to dig up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If working in the notebook the following

```
s[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[1/2^# &, n, 1, Defer[Plus[##]] &]
```

will produce an expression that can be copied, pasted and would evaluate as if the sum was explicitly typed in.

Alternatively you can build a visual resemblance of the sum using `Row`:

```
s[n_Integer?Positive] := Row[Table[1/2^k, {k, 1, n}], "+"]
```

Comment: That first one is so cool! ;-)

Comment: @Sasha How would you handle this one: `s[n_Integer?Positive] := Row[Table[(-1)^k/2^k, {k, 1, n}], "+"]`. That is, how would you get the signs to alternate?

Comment: You would need to either use `Riffle` or `Row[ Flatten[ {If[ Negative[#], "-", "+"], #}& /@ Table[ (-1)^k/2^k, {k, n}]]]`

Comment: `f[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Sum[(-1)^k/2^k x^k, {k, 1, n}] /. {Plus :> Inactive[Plus], x -> 1}`